# Aggregating and storing data from mulitple sources

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm unsure of whether this question is more of a technical or business question, but nonetheless, would definitely like some input from the community.

In short, I am looking to develop something that can stream data from multiple sources. Some may be from APIs, whilst others might be in the form of unstructured data.

My question is, would something like Kafka/any other alternative be a useful platform for this? I'm looking for a solution that can help house the different types of data in a single warehouse before transporting it to a database for querying and analysis.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka doesn't source information. It stores it.

Kafka *Connect* allows sourcing data. But, so does Apache NiFI, KNIME, Streamsets, Talend and similar tools.

Kafka is one piece of the puzzle, but sounds like you need an ETL worflow builder, not simply Kafka.

Also, keep in mind that Kafka was orginally designed for transferring data to Hadoop (which could be replaced with cloud storage such as S3 too), where it can be kept as raw as possible for analytical purposes, **not** a Database